# Php file write through terminal but not from browser

Tags: php

On my CentOS machine I have installed PHP. When I log onto that machine from another machine(fedora) through ssh and run a PHP script for writing to a file, it works perfectly.

But when I open a browser from my fedora machine and open the same PHP script, it fails to open that file for writing. The browser works for read and other echo commands.

I don't get the reason why is it happening. What would be a quick solution to my problem?

Comment: can you check the owner+group of this file which I guess is apache.apache has the permission to write to the target location

Comment: sounds like a permission issue. check if the file has write permission.

Comment: even after chmod 777 my_file.txt, it doesn't work.
not even after chown+chgrp  apache my_file.txt.

Answer (score 0):

When you use CLI, you execute script as user that you logged in as through SSH. On the other hand, when you execute a script through a web browser and your have PHP installed as Apache module, it is running as `apache` user on CentOS ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58157/what-is-the-equivalent-for-www-data-for-centos)).

These two users may have different permissions, so one has permissions to write to the file and other does not.

Long story short: change file permissions so `apache` user can write to it.

Comment: 1. Can i change the user apache in httpd.conf file ?
2. I changed it to the same user as i log in, but still from browser i have only read permission.